# LinearOptimization - how to solve with vector constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, vector, constraint

I have the following linear program that I am able to solve in MATLAB. However, I want to move to Mathematica.

For some fixed constants $n$, $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ and fixed $(n+1)$-dimensional vector $p$, we have the following optimization variables: $(n+1)$-dimensional vectors $y$ and $r$  and a constant $s$. The components of the vectors are labelled by index $k$ which runs from $0$ to $n$. The linear program is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\inf \quad & s \\
\text { s.t. } \quad & y_{k}-r_{k}+p_{k} \geq 0, \forall k \\
\quad & y_{k} \geq 0, \forall k \\
\quad& 0 \leq r_{k} \leq s, \forall k \\
& \Sigma_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) r_{k}=1, \\
& \Sigma_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right)y_{k} \leq \varepsilon .
\end{aligned}
$$

In MATLAB, this can be solved as follows

```
%Declaring input variables
n = 10; 
eps = 0.01;
delta = 0.2; 

for i = 1:n+1
    p(i, 1) = delta^(i-1)*(1-delta)^(n-i+1);
    nck(1,i) = nchoosek(n, i-1);
end
   
%Start optimization
cvx_begin        
   variable y(n+1)
   variable r(n+1)
   variable s
       
   minimize(s)
   subject to
        y >= 0;
        r >= 0;
        r <= s*ones(n+1, 1)
        y - r + p >= 0;
        nck*r ==1;
        nck*y <= eps;
cvx_end
```

How does one do vector constraints in Mathematica? Here is my attempt but I am not sure how to proceed from here

```
n = 10;
delta = 1/5;
eps = 1/50;
pvec = Array[p, n + 1];
nckvec = Array[nck, n + 1];
yvec = Array[y, n + 1];
rvec = Array[r, n + 1];

For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++, pvec[[i]] = delta^(i - 1)*(1 - delta)^(n - i + 1)]
For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++, nckvec[[i]] = Binomial[n, i]]

c1 = Thread[rvec . nckvec == 1];
c2 = Thread[yvec . nckvec <= eps];
c3 = Thread[yvec - rvec + pvec >= 0];
c4 = Thread[0 <= rvec];
c5 = Thread[0 <= yvec];
c6 = Thread[rvec <= s*ConstantArray[1, n + 1]];

constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6];
```

I get an error when I try to join the constraints and I am also not sure how the final linear program solving using, say, LinearOptimization should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: I have assumed that $p_k = \delta^k(1-\delta)^{n-k}$, as in OPs code.*

**Solution 1.** One could use `Minimize`:

```
opt[delta_,eps_,n_]:=With[{p=(delta^#*(1-delta)^(n-#))&},
  Minimize[
    (*function and constraints*)
    {s,
    Table[y[k]-r[k]+p[k]>=0,{k,0,n}],
    Table[y[k]>=0,{k,0,n}],
    Table[0<=r[k]<=s,{k,0,n}],
    Sum[Binomial[n,k]*r[k],{k,0,n}]==1,
    Sum[Binomial[n,k]*y[k],{k,0,n}]<=eps},  
    (*variables*)
    Flatten[{s,Table[{y[k],r[k]},{k,0,n}]}]
]];
```

For example

```
opt[1/5,1/50,10]
```

gives

```
{1706527/19531250,{s->1706527/19531250,y[0]->0,r[0]->1706527/19531250,y[1]->1/500,r[1]->1126701/39062500,y[2]->0,r[2]->65536/9765625,y[3]->0,r[3]->16384/9765625,y[4]->0,r[4]->4096/9765625,y[5]->0,r[5]->1024/9765625,y[6]->0,r[6]->256/9765625,y[7]->0,r[7]->64/9765625,y[8]->0,r[8]->16/9765625,y[9]->0,r[9]->4/9765625,y[10]->0,r[10]->1/9765625}}
```

**Solution 2.** One could use `LinearOptimization`. It is essentially a copy and paste of solution 1 with some minor adjustments:

```
opt2[delta_,eps_,n_]:=With[{p=(delta^#*(1-delta)^(n-#))&},
  LinearOptimization[s,
    {Table[y[k]-r[k]+p[k]>=0,{k,0,n}],
     Table[y[k]>=0,{k,0,n}],
     Table[0<=r[k]<=s,{k,0,n}],
     Sum[Binomial[n,k]*r[k],{k,0,n}]==1,
     Sum[Binomial[n,k]*y[k],{k,0,n}]<=eps},
     Flatten[{s,Table[{y[k],r[k]},{k,0,n}]}]
]];
```

With this one should have more control, see for example the `Method` option.

**Note.** These solutions have the advantage that one can simply write down symbolic inequalities. Sometimes it may make sense to set up the problem in terms of matrices and use `LinearProgramming`.